# Converter para a nomenclatura do R$

Tags: javascript

Colegas.

Estou pegando o valor de um produto em javascript da seguinte forma:

```
totalGeralSomar.toFixed(2)
```

Só que ele me retorna da seguinte forma: 1400.00. Teria algum meio de retornar 1.400,00?

Comment: Você também pode usar um NumberFormat como o do seguinte exemplo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yurmmfns/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara usa essa função em javascript:

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
var n = this, 
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
   return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
 };
```

E usa assim:

```
(1400).formatMoney(2, ',', '.');
```

(**teu_numero**).formatMoney(**casas_decimais**, '**separador2**', '**separador1**');

O resultado vai ser:

```
1.400,00
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando `javaScript` puro, você pode utilizar o método [Replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) para fazer o que deseja. Abaixo deixarei duas funções, uma para formatar o valor formatado, e outro para retirar a formatação e retornar o valor como inteiro, caso necessite usar o mesmo no javascript.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 
var test = 'R$ 1.700,90';
 
 
function getMoney( str )
{
        return parseInt( str.replace(/[\D]+/g,'') );
}
function formatReal( int )
{
        var tmp = int+'';
        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
        if( tmp.length > 6 )
                tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");
 
        return 'R$' + tmp;
}
 
 
var int = getMoney( test );
//alert( int );
 
 
console.log( formatReal( 1000 ) );
console.log( formatReal( 19990020 ) );
console.log( formatReal( 12006 ) );
console.log( formatReal( 111090 ) );
console.log( formatReal( 1111 ) );
console.log( formatReal( 120090 ) );
console.log( formatReal( int ) );
 
 
</script>
```

Fonte: [Formatar Moeda](http://wbruno.com.br/expressao-regular/formatar-em-moeda-reais-expressao-regular-em-javascript/)

**Obs.:** Para ver o resultado, basta executar o código com o `console` de seu navegador aberto (F12).